# Does angular 14 version's mfe work with angular 12 version's shell application?

Tags: angular, backwards-compatibility, nrwl-nx, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

We have a microfrontend which is currently on angular 12. This microfrontend is being used in multiple shells apps (all of them currently on angular 12).

We are looking to upgrade the microfrontend app to angular 14 while making sure that it supports the angular 12 shell applications for a while until all shell applications move to angular 14.

We used `scriptType: type/javascript` to ensure backward compatibility as mentioned in the migration guides. But we are seeing issues in making this ng14 mfe work in ng12 shell app.

[image]

Is it possible to make an angular 12 shell application consume an mfe built with angular 14?

Comment: Have you imported CommonModule in your module?

Comment: @techguy yeah, added CommonModule in the exposed module imports but still getting these errors which is confusing